# I want to query the content of the json inside column like below

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I am saving JSON data my SQL server 2016 table and I want to query the table by applying where clause on the JSON like below.

```
select c.customer_details.name.fullName 
from j_customer c 
where c.customer_details.name.fullName like '%Gopi%';
```

this is possible in oracle but in mssql it gives the error like below

> Cannot call methods on nvarchar(max).

Comment: What query did you use to save to table `j_customer`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going thru internet finally I found out that there is a method called JSON_VALUE() which should be used for finding the content of the json. The syntax for mssql is like this.

`select *
from j_customer  where  JSON_VALUE(c.customer_details, '$.name.fullName') = 'C';`

Comment: Yes this works, more details can be found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood it, you have stored your JSON data into the table using a query like below

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '"Customer_details":{"name":{"fullName":"Dhruv Joshi"}}'

 INSERT INTO j_customer
 SELECT * 
 FROM OPENJSON(@json)
 WITH (---some columns 
       fullName nvarchar(max) '$.Customer_details.name.fullName'
     )
```

In such cases you can simply query your table like below

```
select c.fullName 
from j_customer c 
where c.fullName like '%Gopi%';
```

In SQL the fully qualified SQL column name usually is like `[DatabaseName].[schema].[tablename].[columnname]`, so here in WHERE clause SQL interprets `c.customer_details.name.fullName` as `c.customer_details`  a column as `c` is a table alias. And then `name.fullname` looks like a method call on the column name which generates the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response..  I tried querying like you have given it dint work..  its saying                 Invalid column name 'fullName'.                                                    I have inserted the JSON as a plain text.. The datatype of the column  customer_details is nvarchar(max)     is this the problem?

Comment: OK. So basically the `customer_details` column of the table `j_customer` table has JSON of which you need to check and parse fullname ?

Comment: Yes exactly..  Does sql server supports this?